# "Sparse" Rank in Business Objects XI Web Intelligence?

Tags: business-objects

In Business Objects XI Web Intelligence the Rank function returns dense results. For example when ranking by "Amount" I want to return the top ten records only. However three records tie for 5th place on "Amount". Result is a total of 12 records: one each for places 1 to 4 and 6 to 10 and 3 records for 5th place.

Desired result is a "sparse" top ten that drops the two lowest ranked records (places 9 and 10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do this and rank customers by amount.

I have 2 objects: [Amount] and [Customernumber].
[Customernumber] is numeric.

I created a new variable:

[varForSorting]=[Amount]*10000000+ToNumber([Customernumber])

Then I rank by the new variable [varForSorting].

Customers with the same Amount will be sorted in Alphabetic order by Customer number. I hope this helps.

Comment: Maria: Thanks. Your general approach works for me. I adapted it a bit because unfortunatly my only Customer Identifier is a key that contains alpha numeric data so ToNumber does not work in my case.

Comment: if your Customernumber is Alphanumeric - you could use Asc function to turn it into number. For example: [VarNumericCustomerNumber]=Asc(Left([CustomerNumber];1)*1000+Asc(Substr([CustomerNumber];2;1))

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I solved it for a change in Account Count over time. This approach allows you to break your dense rank ties using other measures in your data provider. Basically you use multiple measures in one rank and decide which measure to rank by first, second, etc:

Step 1: Determine the change amount
v_Account_Count_Delta_Amount
=([v_Account_Count_After] - [v_Account_Count_Before])

Step 2: Rank the change amounts (this is where ties and dense rank cause multiple rows to be returned)
v_Account_Count_Delta_Amount_Rank
=NoFilter(Rank([v_Account_Count_Delta_Amount]))

Step 3: Compute the tie breaking rank using other measures
v_MonthToDateMeasuresRank
=NoFilter(Rank([Month To Date Sva]+ [Bank Share Balance] + [Total Commitment]))

Step 4: Compute a combined rank that is now free from ties and weight your ranks however you choose
v_Account_Count_Combined_Rank
=Rank([v_Account_Count_Delta_Amount_Rank]* 1000000 + [v_MonthToDateMeasuresRank];Bottom)

Step 5: Filter your data block for v_Account_Count_Combined_Rank <= 10

Ultimately depending on your data it could still result in a tie unless you take the additional step of ranking by some other unique attribute that you can turn to a number (see Maria Ruchko's answer for that bit of magic using Customer Number). I tried to do that with RowIndex() and LineNumber() but could not get usable results. My measures when added together happen to never tie so this works for my specific data blob.